# How to Solve Controller Error in Laravel6?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-eloquent-resource

I am getting `AdminController` error, and i am unable to solve this. I am using namespace in web files. Please let me know where i am mistaking.
My error is this..

```
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController] does not exist.
```

Here are my web.php file

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->name('admin.')->middleware('can:manage-users')->group(function(){
Route::resource('/users', 'UsersController',['except'=>['show','create','store']]);
Route::resource('/dashboard', 'AdminController');
Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController');
});
```

Here are my AdminController.php File..

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use App\Admin;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 class AdminController extends Controller
  {
 public function index()
 {
    return view('admin.index');
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error caused by `namespace` :

```
Route::namespace('Admin')

// Controllers within the `App\Http\Controllers\Admin` namespace
```

You need to remove `namespace` or create `AdminController`, `UsersController`, and `BlogController` under `Controllers\Admin` folder and namespace.